# Designing Systems Organizational Structure Representation

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, data-structures, architecture, structure

I'm at the begging of designing a System.
and it's essential for it to have a very flexible Structure that will represent the organization.

**Essential the requirements are simple:**

1. Have a hierarchy of Containers (Organizational Units)
2. Containers will contain other entities (including other containers), entities such as:

   - Groups that can contain Users
   - Calendars
   - etc...
3. There is also a requirement to facilitate the permission and registration process according to the structure.
4. Users\ Groups can be registered with different roles\ permissions to other Containers and that will grant them permissions with the same role to all other entities, there is also the capability to define managers for groups and calendars.

---

**Initial thoughts:**

1. Using the "Composite" design pattern to represent an entity:

   - [[Interface]] IEntity --> int ID, string Name ...
2. Every entity will implement the same interface
3. The Container Entity will hold a list of children that will reference to these entities.
4. Each entity will hold a "Permissions Tree" that will hold Lists of Users at the leafs, this tree will represent the role and way a User is registers to an Entity as a manager. i.e. if a user is register as an Owner through a group the tree will show: Owners --> Group1 --> Users 1.

**Contemplation:**

1. Should each entity have a Delete\ Add method of its own ? defined at the interface level or should there be a different class some sort of an "EntitiesManager" that will handle all the tasks of adding editing and deleting entities.
2. How should i model my database to hold the Permission Tree Info ?

I'll be very happy to hear any ideas, corrections, lessons learned or suggestions on the topic.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your contemplation I'd suggest following:

1. Assuming you are not aware of all entities now and they could have
   pretty different structure you should better encapsulate logic of
   creating/deleting in the entity class. Having more common superclass
   with default implementation would be a good idea.
2. About permission tree. Are you already done with entities model for
   this? For your case best approach is top-down, it's rather more
   straightforward to map entity model to database model when you
   already have it :)

Comment: Thanks.. just to see if I understand... You suggest to use CRUD operations using the specific Entity Class. so if i want to add another Container it will look something like that: MyContainer.Add() and that will add him to the data base. I thought to use a Domain Manager Class some sort of a FACADE that will help me to create the entities e.g. DomainManager.AddEntity(theEntity, ParentEntity).

Comment: Yes. If CRUD logic is totally straightforward for all entities this approach is the best. But lets consider the case when you have 50 different entities with very specific CRUD logic. I don't mean the cascade deletion that could be implemented on the database level. I mean something like 'please create default set of privileges for this new user'. Your DomainManager class will be blown up. On the other hand during typical operations with entities you will always have easy access to CRUD logic with no need to obtain DomainManager instance.